# display openx ads in html page bundled with fire fox extension .xpi

Tags: firefox, openx, ads

I need to display openx ads in one of my html file bundled with firefox extension (xpi). No ads are shown once it is accessed in chrome context. please let me know how to display ads in html page bundled with xpi.

Thanks 
Anand

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what exactly is your problem because you didn't say what code you used, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened (what messages you got in the Error Console). Is there any reason you don't just serve a page from your server over http:// ? There would be no problem in displaying ads there.